# How to manage USB on Android?

Tags: android, usb, port, device

CODE IDEA:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    HashMap<String,UsbDevice> stringUsbDeviceHashMap=manager.getDeviceList();
    Log.e("asdadd", String.valueOf(stringUsbDeviceHashMap.size()));
}

5310-5310/com.example.AppUSB E/asdadd﹕ 0
```

CMD ADB:

```
 C:\Users\Serg>adb devices
 List of devices attached
 DMJNPRCAP7IJGQFA        device
```

Why do I get 0 for the connected devices, if we have 1 single connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`adb` list connected devices from your computer's point of view, whereas `UsbManager.getDeviceList()` literally lists usb connected devices to your Android device...

`UsbManager.getDeviceList()` returns a list of `UsbDevice` which is defined like so by the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice.html):

> This class represents a USB device attached to the android device with the android device acting as the USB host. Each device contains one or more UsbInterfaces, each of which contains a number of UsbEndpoints (the channels via which data is transmitted over USB).

Comment: For example, if I connect mouse to in Android in connector USB, it sees 1 device?

Comment: It should. It simply list devices connected to your Android device (when Android is in host mode), not the host USB that has your Android device attached to (which adb does).